# PHP/MySQL - Constantly Returning 0

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hey so I am trying to retrieve how many keys a user already has and how many their account allows them to have and then calculate the percentage and have it display, while I do know that this code below

```
$SQL1 = $odb -> prepare("SELECT `licenses` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username");
$SQL1 -> execute(array(':username' => $username));
$maxKeys = $SQL1 -> fetchColumn(0);
```

For some reason the following code continues to return 0 even thought there are multiple entries in the table with my current user as owner

```
$SQL = $odb -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `licensetable` WHERE `owner` = $username");
$SQL -> execute(array());
$keysUsed = $SQL -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I know it has to be something so simple but I can not figure it out for the life of me.
The tables structure follows

```
SELECT `id`, `key`, `owner` FROM `licensetable`
```

**Full original page source**

```
    <?php
    ob_start();
    require_once('include/db.php');
    require_once('include/initialize.php');
    if(!($user->LoggedIn())){
        header('location: login');
        die();
    }else{
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        $SQL = $odb -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `licensetable` WHERE `owner` = $username");
        $SQL -> execute(array());
        $keysUsed = $SQL -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $SQL1 = $odb -> prepare("SELECT `licenses` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username");
        $SQL1 -> execute(array(':username' => $username));
        $maxKeys = $SQL1 -> fetchColumn(0);
        $keyPercentage = ($keysUsed / $maxKeys) * 100;
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>SQL</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1 class="page-header">Home</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <?php echo $keyPercentage;
                    echo $maxKeys;
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So the field is `username` or `owner`?

Comment: @u_mulder In the licensetable (the second snippet of code) the field is owner

Comment: Why do you have spaces when accessing object methods? `$maxKeys = $SQL1 -> fetchColumn(0)`. This isn't causing your issue, but it's bad practice to be do that. You don't need the space.

Comment: @BugHunterUK Will clean that up, thank you :)

Comment: Also, second example, don't pass variables directly into the query. You're leaving yourself vulnrable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try (Edited)

Top of page -

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
require_once('include/db.php');
```

Query -

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as val FROM `licensetable` WHERE `owner` = :user");
$query = $odb->prepare($sql);
$query->bindValue(':user', $username);
$query->execute();

$keysUsed = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $keysUsed['val'];
```

Certainly works locally on a test table.

Comment: Hmm no luck with that either unfortunately.

Comment: Then the issue isn't likely to be the SQL query as it's pretty simple. What are you getting if you `var_dump($username)`? Any other errors?

Comment: Just tried it and got 500 server error. Have no clue what the issue is now, this is simply a site for me to learn with so lost at this point.

Comment: Can you update the initial question with all your code?

Comment: `session_start();` at top of the page might help - it seems to be behaving like $username is present but not set to a value which would explain a lot

Comment: You are a life saver :D I had tried to add that to top but before I tested your snippet I removed it. Thank you I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, just a bit of an oversight. We've all done the same at some point